# How do I require at least one checkbox to be selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, checkbox

Part of my HTML form looks like this:

```html
<p>Please select your preferred time slot:</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="am" name="am" value="AM">
<label for="am">AM (09:00-13:00)</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="pm" name="pm" value="PM">
<label for="pm">PM (13:00-18:00)</label><br>
```

I'd like for *at least* one of the checkboxes to be selected as a requirement of the form being submitted. I'd also like the option of both boxes being ticked at the same time. At the moment, if I leave both unselected, the form is still submitted.

I considered using the required property but I can't figure out how to utilise it without making both required.

Comment: If you want the two to be selectable at the same time you should take a look at the [submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) event to validate your form, or else use a required radio button as suggested

Answer (score 0):

- Change the `type` from `"checkbox"` to `"radio"`
- all radio buttons must share a common `[name]` value (ex. all are `name="m"`)
- then add `required` to only one of them.
- add another radio button with both values or something that represents both AM and PM slots.

```html
<form>
  <fieldset style="width: max-content">
    <legend>Please select your preferred time slot:</legend>
    <input id="am" name="m" type="radio" value="AM" required>
    <label for="am">AM (09:00-13:00)</label><br>
    <input id="pm" name="m" type="radio" value="PM">
    <label for="pm">PM (13:00-18:00)</label><br>
    <input id="ap" name="m" type="radio" value="AP">
    <label for="ap">AM/PM (09:00-18:00)</label><br>
    <button style="font: inherit; float: right;">Done</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: The question says **at least one**, if you switch to radio buttons then it will restrict it to **exactly one** (i.e. will prevent two or more being selected).

Comment: Yeah, that's why I updated it with a 3rd option.

Answer (score 0):

Just check on input whether any of the checkboxes is selected. If not - reselect the changed checkbox:

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

setValidity();

checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.addEventListener('input', e => {
  [...checkboxes].some(checkbox => checkbox.checked) || (e.target.checked = true)
  setValidity();
}));

function setValidity(){
  const validity = 
  [...checkboxes].some(checkbox => checkbox.checked) ? '' : 'The time slot is required';
  [...checkboxes].at(-1).setCustomValidity(validity);
}
```

```html
<form>
<p>Please select your preferred time slot:</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="am" name="am" value="AM">
<label for="am">AM (09:00-13:00)</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="pm" name="pm" value="PM">
<label for="pm">PM (13:00-18:00)</label><br><br>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```